# Trying to display short code content in template file with do_shortcode()

Tags: templates, shortcode

I installed the [WP Issuu plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-issuu/) on a site and tried to use `do_shortcode()` to render the shortcode in the template file. Strangely it doesn't work, although it does for the `[gallery]` shortcode.

I.e. this works:

```
echo do_shortcode('[gallery link=file]');
```

But this doesn't work:

```
echo do_shortcode('[issuu width=420 height=272 documentId=120118010023-8b7bf623bdd642d98252f310d62f1625]');
```

After some research, I found that this would work too:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', '[issuu width=420 height=272 documentId=120118010023-8b7bf623bdd642d98252f310d62f1625]');
```

Any idea what's going on and how I can solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP Issuu plugin doesn't use the shortcode API. So you can't use it like a regular shortcode. The plugin is a filter for the_content, that's why your solution did work.

If you want to solve this (use do_shortcode) you have to rewrite the plugin so it uses the shortcode API.